# Relating the standard deviation of a logarithm to the linear standard deviation

Tags: statistics, logarithms

I'm reading a paper where they give the standard deviation of some measured data as  $\sigma_{\log_{10}E} = 0.5$, meaning the standard deviation of the base 10 logarithm of the variable $E$. Assume that the mean $\mu$ is $10^{2.7}$, so that the logarithmed mean is $2.7$. How would I go about transforming these quantities to the linear scale, i.e. $\sigma_{E}$?

My goal is to plot the pdf on a linear scale, say $E$ ranging from $10^1$ to $10^3$. The reason that I don't simply plot the gaussian in log-space is that I'm planning to integrate it over the linear scale.

Comment: How does $\mu_E=10^{2.7}\implies\mu_{\log_{10}E}=\log_{10}(10^{2.7})$? Arithmetic mean of $\log E$ is the logarithm of the geometric mean of $E$.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the measured data is normally distributed?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Yes it is

Comment: @Martin I see. In that case you'll have to be a bit careful when trying to do theoretic computations (evaluating integrals and such): no matter what $\mu$ and $\sigma$, your data could, in principle, have a negative value, and $\log(x)$ doesn't exist when $x <0$.

Comment: Or do you mean that the logarithm of the data is more or less normally distributed? In that case the original data is lognormally distributed and there are formulas for the mean and standard deviation of a lognormal distribution.